# Can I cache redirect result without caching the redirect?

Tags: php, caching, redirect

On a certain site I need to count the amount of times some image are displayed. This is solved by directing the image src to a php script that does the counting and then redirects to the actual image using 302. The script part works fine and is launched every time the image is requested, but I'm not sure if the output image is cached by the browser or how to check if it is. My current assumption is that the is not cached because it was pointed by the 302 redirect.

Ideally it would be perfect if I could achieve this result:

1. Image is requested via url with php script
2. The script does a 302 redirect to the actual image
3. The browser recognizes the address of the 302 redirect and loads cached image

I guess it would depend on the browser, but is it even possible to achieve this result?

P.S. It's more of a theoretical question, as it won't matter much for my particular problem (the images are quite small).

---

I did what CBroe suggested and now I know that it works how I wanted it to (at least in Firefox). The browser is smart enough to load the cached version of images even if I redirect to them from my script via 302.

Comment: _“but I'm not sure […] how to check if [the output image is cached]”_ – well use the network panel in your browser’s developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be yes. My methods of testing this were originally limited to FireBug, but in [FireFox developer tools network tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) I was able to see all the redirects that happened and those were done in the way I hoped for.

Previously I wrote that in a comment to the question, but I probably should have posted it as an answer.